# Issue in Selenium script execution using .bat

Tags: selenium-webdriver, batch-file

I am trying to run a selenium script via .bat file. But I am getting failure in CMD. The script runs fine when ran via eclipse ( test case runs properly as testng class and as testng suite). But when i run the .bat it shows me below

```
C:\Users\sagar.pawaskar\Documents\eclipse-workspace\sel>set ProjectPath=C:\Users\sagar.pawaskar\Documents\eclipse-workspace\sel

C:\Users\sagar.pawaskar\Documents\eclipse-workspace\sel>echo C:\Users\sagar.pawaskar\Documents\eclipse-workspace\sel
C:\Users\sagar.pawaskar\Documents\eclipse-workspace\sel

C:\Users\sagar.pawaskar\Documents\eclipse-workspace\sel>set classpath=C:\Users\sagar.pawaskar\Documents\eclipse-workspace\sel\bin;C:\Users\sagar.pawaskar\Documents\eclipse-workspace\sel\lib\*

C:\Users\sagar.pawaskar\Documents\eclipse-workspace\sel>echo C:\Users\sagar.pawaskar\Documents\eclipse-workspace\sel\bin;C:\Users\sagar.pawaskar\Documents\eclipse-workspace\sel\lib\*
C:\Users\sagar.pawaskar\Documents\eclipse-workspace\sel\bin;C:\Users\sagar.pawaskar\Documents\eclipse-workspace\sel\lib\*

C:\Users\sagar.pawaskar\Documents\eclipse-workspace\sel>java org.testng.TestNG C:\Users\sagar.pawaskar\Documents\eclipse-workspace\sel\test1.xml

===============================================
Suite
Total tests run: 1, Passes: 0, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


C:\Users\sagar.pawaskar\Documents\eclipse-workspace\sel>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

**Run.bat file contents**

```
set ProjectPath=C:\Users\sagar.pawaskar\Documents\eclipse-workspace\sel
echo %ProjectPath%
set classpath=C:\Users\sagar.pawaskar\Documents\eclipse-workspace\sel\bin;C:\Users\sagar.pawaskar\Documents\eclipse-workspace\sel\lib\*
echo %classpath%
java org.testng.TestNG C:\Users\sagar.pawaskar\Documents\eclipse-workspace\sel\test1.xml
pause
```

**TestNG report shows**

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.create(java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService)'
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.<init>(UrlChecker.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:197)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:188)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:79)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
    at src.NewTest.f(NewTest.java:22)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1510)
... Removed 26 stack frames
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried my below sample testng project to run from a `bat` file.

```
package packageone;

import java.io.File;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class ActionOne {
    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    public void mainone() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","Z:/CloudBLM/assets/driver/chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        System.out.println("BeforeTest");
    }
    
    @Test
    public void TestOne() {
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    }
    
    @AfterTest
    public void aftertest() {
        System.out.println("AfterTest");
        driver.close();
    }

}
```

And My `testng.xml` will be as shown below

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Sample" verbose="1">
    <test name="Sample Test">
        <classes>
            <class name="packageone.ActionOne" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Tried with my below Command line code which have executed my testng test

```
java -cp "External Jar File folder path";"Bin folder path" org.testng.TestNG "testng.xml path"
```

1. External Jar File folder path:This folder should contain all the jar file required for project to run.Create a lib folder in your project directory also add this in the build path under eclipse. It shouldn't contain any sub directory and a jar file into it. You can find the jar files in the folder from the image below.

[image]
[image]

2. Bin folder path: Which will be in default in your project directory like `D:\Selenium files\Workspace\SQA\bin`
3. And your `Testng.xml` file path which will be like `D:\Selenium files\Workspace\SQA\testng.xml`

While running this will make successful testng run as shown in image below
[image]

And i guess the real problem is in your `bat` script, you have given library file path as `C:\Users\sagar.pawaskar\Documents\eclipse-workspace\sel\lib\*` but you may have selenium jar file into a folder named "libs" since unzipped selenium jar file will come with this [folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7TWb.png) so the possible fix is to move the selenium jar file from this folder to your created `lib` [folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xl8ZZ.png).

This also will fix this issue

Comment: Thanks Mohamed. My setup is proper as you mentioned. also, my selenium jar folder is named lib. not sure why I am seeing the issue.

Comment: Whether it has been fixed or still it is occuring?

Comment: issue is still occuring?

Comment: Shall i know which command you have used whether command from my answer or else command which you have posted in your question

Comment: Also paste your lib directory snapshot like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/xl8ZZ.png

Comment: I tried ur cmd. but still the same issue

Comment: Paste your directory screenshot or give its snapshot link

Comment: It works for me now. I just created a whole new java project. added jars again. Then it worked.

Comment: @Safaee Kindly mark the answer as accepted if it helped you by clicking on the check mark aside the answer

Answer (score 0):

because of testNG plugin ,you are able to execute your scripts on your IDE

however there are three ways to execute your testNG class :

- xmlSuite
- run as testNG class
- creating the object of testNG class directly

while executing it through

> **.bat**

Please create a main class with main method ,Also please create the

> **.jar**

please refer the below code:

public class TestNGMainClass {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestNG testSuite = new TestNG();
    testSuite.setTestClasses(new Class[] { Test5.class });
    testSuite.addListener(new Test5SuiteListener());
    testSuite.setDefaultSuiteName("My Test Suite");
    testSuite.setDefaultTestName("My Test");
    testSuite.setOutputDirectory("/Users/temp/testng-output");
    testSuite.run();
}
```

}